# Install PHP CodeSniffer / PHP MessDetector

Tags: php, phpstorm, phpcodesniffer

I am new to PEAR thing in PHP and I want to install **PHP CodeSniffer** & **PHP MessDetector**. I am using **PHP Storm** as my editor.

My XAMPP installation directory is D i.e. `D:\xampp\`

I have downloaded CodeSniffer and Mess Detector and installed it manually (copy files and folders) under below location

```
D:\xampp\php\PEAR\PHP\
```

What I need to know is

```
1) Is the file location correct to install PEAR Packages ?

2) How can I set custom ruleset for Code Sniffer and Mess Detector in PHP Storm ?
```

Once its done, I then need to install **Magento-ECG / Coding-Standard** - https://github.com/magento-ecg/coding-standard

Thanks.

Comment: You should use *pear* itself to install those packages -- simple copy (most likely) will not do much.

Comment: I am using a windows system and found it confusing to install using pear.

Comment: I'm using Windows too. Are you saying that executing single command **`pear install PHP_CodeSniffer`** is confusing?

Comment: No, actually I did it but it shows error for mkdir in C: drive and so i opted to install manually

Comment: Whatever -- it's PEAR issue (most likely you have not configured/installed PEAR itself properly) -- your should ensure that PEAR is working first.

Comment: Regarding custom ruleset: it can be set in `Settings | Inspections | PHP` -- find correct inspection there and choose ruleset you want to use (but provide correct path to CodeSniffer/MessDetector first in `Settings | PHP`)

Comment: PEAR is installed at include_path= D:\xampp\php\PEAR and CodeSniffer files and folders are too uploaded at D:\xampp\php\PEAR\PHP\

Comment: Posting the exact mkdir error might help a lot ;-) 

It sounds like a permission problem.

Comment: _If_ your PEAR configuration was correct, then with the file locations you mentioned it should have no reason to try and create a directory on your __C:__ drive …

Comment: PEAR configuration is fine but it would be great if you can let me know about CodeSniffer installation path location

Comment: When I try to load my custom ruleset for CodeSniffer it says, check php code sniffer tool configuration

Comment: If you can't install the CodeSniffer via PEAR because it raises errors then your PEAR installation is misconfigured. Have you tried to install something else?